# 403 on brightdata ws endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

here is my code

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-core");
const SBR_WS_ENDPOINT = "example link for stackoverflow"
async function main() {
  console.log("Connecting to Scraping Browser...");
  const browser = await puppeteer.connect({
    browserWSEndpoint: SBR_WS_ENDPOINT
  });
  try {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    console.log("Connected! Navigating to https://example.com...");
    await page.goto("https://example.com");
    console.log("Navigated! Taking page screenshot to page.png...");
    await page.screenshot({ path: "./page.png", fullPage: true });
    console.log("Done!");
  } finally {
    await browser.close();
  }
}

main().catch(err => {
  console.error(err.stack || err);
  process.exit(1);
});
```

and here is my response

```
ErrorEvent {
  [Symbol(kTarget)]: WebSocket {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] { open: [Function], error: [Function] },
    _eventsCount: 2,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _binaryType: 'nodebuffer',
    _closeCode: 1006,
    _closeFrameReceived: false,
    _closeFrameSent: false,
    _closeMessage: <Buffer >,
    _closeTimer: null,
    _extensions: {},
    _paused: false,
    _protocol: '',
    _readyState: 3,
    _receiver: null,
    _sender: null,
    _socket: null,
    _bufferedAmount: 0,
    _isServer: false,
    _redirects: 0,
    _autoPong: true,
    _url: 'nothing here =/',
    _originalIpc: false,
    _originalSecure: true,
    _originalHostOrSocketPath: 'brd.superproxy.io:9222',
    _req: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 4,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: true,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: true,
      maxRequestsOnConnectionReached: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      strictContentLength: false,
      _contentLength: 0,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      _closed: true,
      _header: 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: Puppeteer 22.6.1\r\n' +
        'Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n' +
        'Sec-WebSocket-Key: x6Vwk0CMzQyPUHP2XWNOzg==\r\n' +
        'Connection: Upgrade\r\n' +
        'Upgrade: websocket\r\n' +
        'Host: brd.superproxy.io:9222\r\n' +
        'Authorization: Basic nothing here '-' ==\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: nop],
      agent: undefined,
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'GET',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
      path: '/',
      _ended: true,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: true,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'brd.superproxy.io',
      protocol: 'https:',
      [Symbol(shapeMode)]: false,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kChunkedBuffer)]: [],
      [Symbol(kChunkedLength)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kSocket)]: [TLSSocket],
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype],
      [Symbol(errored)]: null,
      [Symbol(kHighWaterMark)]: 16384,
      [Symbol(kRejectNonStandardBodyWrites)]: false,
      [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null,
      [Symbol(kAborted)]: true,
      [Symbol(kError)]: undefined
    },
    [Symbol(shapeMode)]: false,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  [Symbol(kType)]: 'error',
  [Symbol(kError)]: Error: Unexpected server response: 403
      at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\wabori\Documents\scrapping\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:912:7)
      at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:519:28)
      at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (node:_http_client:698:27)
      at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:119:17)
      at TLSSocket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:540:22)
      at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:519:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:559:12)
      at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:510:3)
      at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:390:5)
      at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23),
  [Symbol(kMessage)]: 'Unexpected server response: 403'
}
```

i'm using brightdata for my webscrape project, i'm already verified the username, host, password and host of data, please help me

i don't have more details for share it i don't have more details for share it i don't have more details for share it i don't have more details for share it i don't have more details for share it i don't have more details for share it